# PrimeNG - ESC not working when dialog contains any dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng

code:

```
<p-dialog header="Title" [(visible)]="display" [style]="{width: '40vw',height: '20vw'}">
    <p-dropdown [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="carsel" appendTo="body"></p-dropdown>
</p-dialog>
```

The hotkey ESC can close the dialog initially, but after I clicking the dropdown the hotkey becomes not working.

PrimeNG version 10

Here I didn't use any ngIf and also explicitly tried closeOnEscape=true, but the problem remains.
Any one know why?

Comment: Interestingly, there are complaints of opposite behavior - pressing Escape when the dropdown (multiselect in this case) is in focus closes the containing dialog. See https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/11044

Comment: Their implementation of this is all messed up. We couldn't take it anymore and implemented a custom directive that hooks up to specifically marked `p-button` that we put in every dialog (which is used to close it), then emiting a click event to that button on `ESC`. This has a drawback of making it impossible to just close the dropdown with `ESC` if it's focused but it solves the original problem.

Comment: You most likely should upgrade to a supported version.  I know it's a pain to upgrade Angular, RxJs, PrimeNG, Jasmine, EsLint and typescript.  I've been doing it since Angular 2.